# Matching on a particular type of a parametric type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to work with an external library that has provided a parametric type like this:

```
data ParametricType a = TypeConstructor a
```

I have a typeclass, something like this:

```
class GetsString a where
    getString :: a -> String
```

and I'd like to execute some code if ParametricType's `a` is a specific type. I've tried narrowing the type when instantiating the typeclass:

```
data HoldsString = HoldsString String

instance GetsString (ParametricType HoldsString) where
    getString (TypeConstructor (HoldsString str)) = str
```

which errors with `Illegal instance declaration for‘GetsString (ParametricType HoldsString)’(All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)`

and I've tried pattern matching on the type:

```
instance GetsString (ParametricType a) where
    getString (TypeConstructor (HoldsString str)) = str
```

for which I receive `Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘HoldsString’‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the instance declaration`.

Is there a way to do this, or am I conceptually on the wrong track here?

Comment: For better inference you want your instance heads not to be nested, as much as you can. If there is an instance for `GetsString HoldsString` then `instance GetsString a => GetsString (ParametricType a)` would be ideal. If you only want it to work for `HoldsString` and no other `GetsString (ParametricType X)` use the [constraint trick for instances](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/) and write it with a type equality in the constraint: `instance a ~ HoldsString => GetsString (ParametricType a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing [the `FlexibleInstances` extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#extension-FlexibleInstances). Put `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` at the top of your file, or do `:set -XFlexibleInstances` if you're typing into GHCi directly, and then your first attempt will work.

Comment: Just to add to this, Haskell is a bit odd in that you'll be enabling a *lot* of compiler extensions in any reasonably-sized project. It's just part of the day-to-day in Haskell. Stephen Diehl had a wonderful blog post summarizing which extensions were harmless, which were useful but fickle, and which were insane. It looks like his site has been taken down, but you can still read it [on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220326220907/http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#classes).

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - thanks, yes - I've noticed others doing this, I've been trying to be a bit conservative myself and get some kind of a grip on vanilla Haskell first.

Comment: @ChrisJHarris Note that in GHC 9.2 and newer, [GHC2021](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/control.html#extension-GHC2021) is enabled by default, which includes this and a whole bunch of other extensions. In a way, it is the new vanilla Haskell.